# How do I define AsyncFunction in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to define an AsyncFunction (please note the big F) in node as described here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction

But I get:

```
AsyncFunction('var1', 'var2', 'let test=var1+var2') (1, 2)
ReferenceError: AsyncFunction is not defined
```

Creating a normal Function object works fine. Does NodeJS not support AsyncFunction?

Comment: @iLuvLogix Yes it does! Thanks! I needed to define the function AsyncFunction first. Very weird solution by the javascript engine developers...

Comment: No worries - caught me off-guard the first time as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the question you're fundamentally asking is what is the syntax for defining an asynchronous function, and not really trying to invoke the constructor of that object.

if so then:

synchronous:

```
function foo()
```

asynchronous:

```
async function bar()
```

Update:
After understanding your comments, I encourage you to re-read the spec:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction

It clearly describes that it is not a global-scope object.  The examples listed below it as well, also describe it's usage which also reinforce the idea that it must be assigned (locally) before usage, so there is a definition of it.

Comment: No, I am not. I am asking why AsyncFunction was not working in Node. I needed to manually assign it first. const AsyncFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(async function(){}).constructor;

Comment: @DanieleTesta Why do you want to use the `AsyncFunction` constructor anyway? It's not a global object specifically because you're expected to use the syntax shown in this answer to create async functions.

Comment: @Lennholm Because the code I want to run is inside a variable. If I define it the "normal" way, I will have to use eval() to execute the code and then async does not work anyways.